# How to find adjoint of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

If we have $A:\mathbb{R}\to M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ as $A(t)=tS$ for some  $S\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Then how can we show that the adjoint $A^*:M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{R}$ $\ \ $is $A^*(M)= \text{Re} (\text{tr}{(M^*S)})$. Since $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})^*=M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R} $ and $\text{Re}$ denotes real part of trace.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the adjoint, \begin{align*}t\,A^*(M)=\langle t,A^*(M)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}&=\langle tS,M\rangle_{M_n(\mathbb{C})}\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\,\mathrm{tr}(tSM^*)\\
&=t\,\mathrm{Re}\,\mathrm{tr}(SM^*)
\end{align*}
Since $t$ is arbitrary, $A^*(M)=\mathrm{tr}(SM^*)$.

Comment: I have done in same way but how does $\langle{tS},{M}\rangle= Re tr (tSM^*)$ does it simply $tr (tSM^*)$ , means how $Re$ comes into play

Comment: It depends on how the inner product is defined. If you consider complex scalars, there should be no real part; but since it is restricted to reals, then yes.